# Jquery-ui tooltip on click

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

I'm trying to make a jquery-ui tooltip show/hide on a click event. Also I don't want it to show hide on mouse enter/leave.

Here is a fiddle with a normal tooltip : http://jsfiddle.net/Michael_0/sLhD9/
(unfortunately jsfiddle doesn't seem to be able to include jquery-ui from google cdn ?).

I had the idea to disabled the tooltip at initialization then enable it on click just before showing it, it works but I can't prevent the tooltip from hiding when the mouse leaves the target.

```
$("#myDiv").tooltip({
    disabled: true,
    content: function () {
        return "<div>Custom content</div>"
    }
});

$("#myDiv").click(function () {
        $(this).tooltip("option", "disabled", false);
        $(this).tooltip("open");
    });
```

Comment: So , you click a button and then tool tip appears ? Then how are you planning it to disappear ?

Comment: @Runcorn it should disappear on the next click but not on mouseleave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to unbind the default event handlers:

```
$("#myDiv").unbind('mouseover');
$("#myDiv").attr('ttVisible','no');
$("#myDiv").click(function() {
    if($("#myDiv").attr('ttVisible') == 'no') {
        $("#myDiv").tooltip('open');
        $("#myDiv").unbind('mouseleave');
        $("#myDiv").attr('ttVisible','yes');
    } else {
        $("#myDiv").tooltip('close');
        $("#myDiv").attr('ttVisible','no');
    }
});
```

You can track the current state however works for you, I used an attribute called ttVisible.  jQuery UI doesn't seem to expose the current state of the tooltip in any way.

Comment: unbind mouseleave doesn't seem to work, could you provide a jsfiddle please ?